# Javascriptvoid(0) wont call function

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I have looked over my code and realized there where a few issues with the script. Now I have sorted it it will not pass through the checking you have the correct funds. i think it has something to do with the way i have declared my variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var money = "<?php echo $ir['money']; ?>";
        var price = 5000;
        function openAccount() {
            var c = confirm("Are you sure you want to open a bank account for <?=money_formatter(price)?>?");
            if(c) {
                $('#main_text').html('Opening account'); 
                $('#main_text').append('Checking you have the correct funds'); 
                if(+money < +price) {
                    $('#main_text').append('<span style="color: red;">Incorrect funds, You need another <?=money_formatter((price)-$ir["money"])?>...</span>');         
                } else {
                    $.post('<?=file?>?open=true&print=1', function(data) {
                      if(data == 'not_enough_money') {
                        $('#main_text').append('Incorrect funds...');       
                      } else if(data == 'opened') {
                        $('#main_text').append('You have succesfully opened your brand new bank account!<a href="javascript:void(0);">&gt;View Account</a>');  
                      }
                    }); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That html is .. wrong. It should be easy to spot when "Viewing HTML Source" on the webpage.

Comment: if you are doing this than i would say dont do this instead  I would use a stylized <button></button>

Comment: Sorted html and still nothing

Comment: Isn't the function called `openAccount()`, yet you have `onClick=new_account();`.

Comment: You should never use GET for an action that changes the data. Use POST for this !

Comment: Already had changed the function name for got to update and changed to post still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot two quotes.

Replace `<a href="javascript:void(0); onClick=new_account();">`
by `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="new_account();">` and everything will work.

Comment: That means that there is one error less... There's something else that's wrong too.